# Windows 10 - adding Wifi Credentials for all users

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking

Windows 10 saves WiFi EAP credentials for the current user only.  That is, when the user logs out, it disconnects from the network and logging in with another user requires entering more credentials. How can I set it to save credentials for all users and stay connected when logged off?

Answer (score 4):

First, export an existing WiFi profile with:

```
netsh wlan export profile name="WifiNetwork" folder="C:\path\" key=clear
```

After that, add it to all users:

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="full path of .xml file" user=all
```

For detailed information refer to this tutorial from [tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3530-backup-restore-wireless-network-profiles-windows-10-a.html):